# Instagram api returns only 1 result for followerlist in android?

Tags: android, instagram

I am trying to get user follower list but when i get it will return me only one result

**Auth Url :**
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=bd587ae855284f8ab0546e93d26fd47e&redirect_uri=http://www.google.com&response_type=code&display=touch&scope=follower_list

Get follower list url below

**Documentation Url :**
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

**MyUrl :**
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=3193214716.bd587ae.da600184da49442384b66b6a54222fae

Comment: Double check your code. It's working . or paste your code here.

Comment: it is return only 1 result i have 3 followers in list

Comment: how to check my accesstoken is right or wrong ?